# Python: Global Class Type vs Instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, global-variables

I'm pretty new to Python, so be somewhat forgiving of stupid questions :)

I am setting up some global const-like data, and I realized that I can do this without the interpreter complaining about it:

```
# ... in prime.py ...

class GlobalData:
    LongList = [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ]

# ... in another module ...

data = prime.GlobalData.LongList[2]
```

Is this safe to use? It's possible the interpreter isn't complaining, but may brake down later for some reason? In case it isn't obvious, my question is about accessing members using a class **type** instead of a class **instance**. For example, inside of `prime.py`, I could have instead named the class `GLOBALDATA` and added `GlobalData = GLOBALDATA()` at the bottom.

In C/C++, I would use a different operator (::), but even then, I wouldn't be allowed to access non-static variable values from a class type without an instance. I'm not comparing the two languages, just making sure my question is understood.

Are both of these acceptable? Is one better for specific situations?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: That *is* a "static" variable. "Non-static" variables are created in `__init__`. (Also if the class just exists to hold a bunch of global data, it's pointless - you could have just used module-level variables.)

Comment: (Also there's no `::` or classes in C.)

Comment: There is no problem with accessing `LongList` static variable both with class and with instance.

Comment: I didn't realize that all variables declared outside of `__init__` were static. Is that true? No idea how I've made it this far without figuring that out. I guess that explains why this works. I'm using the class to group a small number of related global values, but I could create a module for those situations. Is the use of a class to group related data a bad idea? For example, if I have several global values that relate to an object-like concept?

Comment: Oh, and you are correct about the lack of `::` and "classes" in C. Bad habit of writing the two languages as one.

Comment: I think I know how I made it this far without figuring it out. Because in Python, `MyClassInstance.SomeRandomThing = X` is allowed even when `SomeRandomThing` was not previously declared as a member. This means I've been declaring statics, and then without realizing it, declaring normal class members with the same names when I use them. I wonder how long I could have continued this way before I figured it out on my own.